# Cómo redireccionar a una página padre con contraseña si se accede a una sub-página? - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirección

En WordPress tengo una página Padre que tiene contraseña (utilizando la opción 'Password Protected' que trae wordpress), el cual si tiene páginas hijo, estas también estarán bloqueadas.

Lo que necesito es:

1.-Si se accede a una sub-página y la página principal está protegida con contraseña, entonces debe redireccionar a la página principal.

2.-Cuando se ingresa la contraseña en la página principal y es correcta, debe redireccionar a la primer página hijo.

Con el siguiente código sólo he logrado realizar otros requerimientos que también me pidieron:

3.-Si se ingresa la contraseña correcta en la página principal entonces automáticamente se desbloquean las subpáginas.

4.- proteger las páginas hijo si el padre tiene establecida una contraseña:

```
function ft_password_protect_children_page_contents( $org_content ){
if ( is_page() ){
    global $post;

    // Grab ancestors
    $ancestors = $post->ancestors;
    
    // Loop through ancestors, grab first one that is password protected
    foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
        if ( post_password_required( $ancestor ) ) {
            $real_post = $post;
            $post = get_post( $ancestor );
            echo get_the_password_form();
            $post = $real_post;
            return;
        }
    }
}
return $org_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'ft_password_protect_children_page_contents' );
```

Me podrían ayudar por favor con el punto 1 y 2!!!
He conseguido este código para redireccionar a la primer página hijo pero no sé como implementarlo a mi código:

```
$pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
                    if ($pagekids) {
                        if (!get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dont_redirect', true)) {
                            $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
                            wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
                            exit;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Para el punto 1**, en un hook como `send_headers` u otro precedente, tendrías que verificar que estés en una página, y revisando sus ancestros ver si el ancestro de mayor orden está protegido con password:

```
 if(!is_page()) return;
 $postId = get_the_ID();
 $post = get_post($postId);
 $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
 if (count($ancestors) === 0) return;

 $ancestor = get_post(end($ancestors));
 if($ancestor->post_password && post_password_required($ancestor) {
   wp_redirect(get_the_permalink($ancestor));
   exit();
 }
```

El último if sólo redirige si el post superior tiene password y no lo has llenado aún. Una vez que lo llenas, eso no se cumple y puedes leer la página hija.

**El punto 2** implica condicionar la navegación a una variable de sesión o una cookie. Ahí tendrías que guardar el permalink del post inicial y redirigir a ese valor guardado cuando la redirección que puse arriba no se gatille. Eso puede llegar a ser riesgoso y te abre un flanco a ataques por exfiltración. Pero, aunque no lo fuera, implica mucha prueba y error como para abordarlo en esta respuesta.

**Edit, 24-02-2022**

Cuando digo que es peligroso permitir que la navegación obedezca a un valor arbitrario, me refiero a que controlar la navegación via un javascript malicioso no es trivial. Al redirigir a lo que sea que diga una cookie o variable de sesión, para un atacante se vuelve mucho más fácil atacar a esos objetivos, sabiendo que con eso te puede hacer navegar donde quiera.